# Android: Extract article main content

Tags: android, html, jsoup, extract

Currently I am creating an Android application which allows to extract main content and picture from a website. Now I am using `Jsoup` API to extract all `p` tags from the HTML. However, it is not a good solution. Any suggestion or better solution enable me to extract main content and picture from a website in Android?

Comment: Due to the sheer size, syntactic and semantic complexity of websites (or even just single web pages), extracting the "main content" algorithmically sounds like a full blown research project.

Comment: I try to search around. That is some open source like Goose is able to extract the main content. But I failed to use it in Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find anything that works for me, so I published Goose for Android, here: https://github.com/milosmns/goose

Some description follows...

> **Document cleaning**
>
> When you pass a URL to Goose, the first thing it starts to do is clean
>   up the document to make it easier to parse. It will go through the
>   whole document and remove comments, common social network sharing
>   elements, convert em and other tags to plain text nodes, try to
>   convert divs used as text nodes to paragraphs, as well as do a general
>   document cleanup (spaces, new lines, quotes, encoding, etc).
>
> **Content / Images Extraction**
>
> When dealing with random article links you're bound to come across the
>   craziest of HTML files. Some sites even like to include 2 or more HTML
>   files per site. Goose uses a scoring system based on clustering of
>   English stop words and other factors that you can find in the code.
>   Goose also does descending scoring so as the nodes move down - the
>   lower their scores become. The goal is to find the strongest grouping
>   of text nodes inside a parent container and assume that's the relevant
>   group of content as long as it's high enough (up) on the page.
>
> Image extraction is the one that takes the longest. Trying to find the
>   most important image on a page proved to be challenging and required
>   to download all the images to manually inspect them using external
>   tools (not all images are considered, Goose checks mime types,
>   dimensions, byte sizes, compression quality, etc). Java's Image
>   functions were just too unreliable and inaccurate. On Android, Goose
>   uses the BitmapFactory class, it is well documented, tested, and is
>   fast and accurate. Images are analyzed from the top node that Goose
>   finds the content in, then comes a recursive run outwards trying to
>   find good images - Goose also checks if those images are ads, banners
>   or author logos, and ignores them if so.
>
> **Output Formatting**
>
> Once Goose has the top node where we think the content is, Goose will
>   try to format the content of that node for the output. For example,
>   for NLP-type applications, Goose's output formatter will just suck all
>   the text and ignore everything else, and other (custom) extractors can
>   be built to offer a more Flipboardy-type experience.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it's not a good solution to use Jsoup?

I've written many web scrapers for different webpages, and in my experience Jsoup is the way to go for that task. You should study the [Jsoup Syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) it is very powerful and with the right selectors you could extract most information from HTML documents very easy. Generally it becomes harder to extract information when the document has no `id`, `class` attributes or other unique features.

Other HTML parsers that might be interesting for you are [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) and [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)

Comment: Thanks for your information. Yes, JSOUP is poweful but I just need to find out more information or open API about HTML parsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [textracto api](https://textracto.com) it automatically identifies the main content of  HTML documents. There is also the opportunity to parse OpenGraph meta data, therefore you were also able to extract a picture (`og:image`).